# combobox not being populated

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a windows form project with a main form. There is a textbox leave event that opens a new form. In that new forms load event i have a combobox item loop that populates the combobox items. It works perfectly fine if run on the main form but doesnt work on the second form. Why doesn't the comboboxes on the secondary form populate when that form is opened via a textbox_leave event from the main form?
this is the leave event

```
 Private Sub tbChartTitle_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles tbChartTitle.Leave
    If Not tbChartTitle.Text = Nothing Then
        frmTitleAttributes.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code that populates one of the comboboxes on the second form (it works if run on a combobox on the main form)

```
 Private Sub frmTitleAttributes_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    InitializeComponent()
    AddFonts()
End Sub
Private Sub AddFonts()
    ' Get the installed fonts collection.
    Dim allFonts As New Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection
    ' Get an array of the system's font familiies.
    Dim fontFamilies() As FontFamily = allFonts.Families

    ' Display the font families.
    For i As Integer = 0 To fontFamilies.Length - 1
        cbxTitleFonts.Items.Add(fontFamilies(i).Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the `Load` handler is hit after you show your form (use break point)

also you can try to call it in the `Shown` event

```
Private Sub frmTitleAttributes_Shown(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) _ 
     Handles frmTitleAttributes.Shown

   AddFonts()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I found that calling initializecomponent in the form load was causing the issue